# Add Item to Specific Table View Row if Available

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, parse-server

I am trying to create a tableView of users from my Parse database that are in the same class (at school). All users have to have a username, but not all will have given the app their full name or set a profile picture. I use this code:

```
let studentsQuery = PFQuery(className:"_User")
studentsQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: studentsArray! as! [AnyObject])

let query2 = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([studentsQuery])

query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error != nil {

        // Display error in tableview

    } else if results! == [] {

        spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

        print("error")

    } else if results! != [] {

        if let objects = results {

            for object in objects {

                if object.objectForKey("full_name") != nil {

                    let studentName = object.objectForKey("full_name")!  as! String

                    self.studentNameResults.append(studentName)


                }

                if object.objectForKey("username") != nil {

                    let studentUsername = object.objectForKey("username")!  as! String

                    self.studentUsernameResults.append(studentUsername)

                }

                if object.objectForKey("profile_picture") != nil {

                    let studentProfilePictureFile = object.objectForKey("profile_picture") as! PFFile

                    studentProfilePictureFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (image: NSData?, error: NSError?) in

                        if error == nil {

                            let studentProfilePicture : UIImage = UIImage(data: image!)!
                            self.studentProfilePictureResults.append(studentProfilePicture)

                        } else {

                            print("Can't get profile picture")

                            // Can't get profile picture

                        }

                        self.studentsTableView.reloadData()

                    })

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                } else {

                    // no image

                }

            }
        }
} else {

    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

    print("error")

}
}
```

This code works fine if all of the users have a username, full_name, and a profile_picture. I can't figure out, however, how to get a `tableView` of the usernames of a user and add a user's name or picture to the user's corresponding `tableViewCell` only if the user has a picture. Here is how my `tableView` is configured:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return studentUsernameResults.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StudentsInClassInformationTableViewCell

        cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.image = studentProfilePictureResults[indexPath.row]

        cell.studentUsernameLabel.text = studentUsernameResults[indexPath.row]

        cell.studentNameLabel.text = studentNameResults[indexPath.row]


        return cell

}
```

The `studentProfilePictureResults`, `studentUsernameResults`, and `studentNameResults` come from arrays of the user's picture, username, and name results pulled from Parse. If a user does not have a profile picture, I get the error, `Index is out of range`. Obviously, this means that there are, say, three names, three usernames, and only two pictures and Xcode doesn't know how to configure the cell. My question: **How can I set a tableView up of a user's username and place their name and profile picture in the same cell, only if they have one?**

Comment: Don't store separate arrays.  Store a single array of the PFObjects and I would suggest you use a dictionary of [username(string):UIImage) for the photos

Comment: @Paulw11 When I query for the user's username, name, and picture, I get all of the results at once, like you are talking about (storing the results in one array). How would I go about storing the username, name, and picture together? I haven't played with dictionaries much , but I thought that they can only store two (2) results. How can I store all three (3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to store the different attributes in different arrays will be a problem, since as you have found, you end up with problems where a particular user doesn't have an attribute.  You could use an array of optionals, so that you could store `nil` for an absent attribute, but it is much simpler to store the `PFObject` itself in a single array and accessing the attributes in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` rather than splitting out the attributes.

Since fetching the photo requires a separate, asynchronous, operation, you can store it separately.  Rather than using an array to store the retrieved photos, which would have the same problem of ordering, you can use a dictionary, indexed by the user id; although for a large number of students it would probably be more efficient to use something like `SDWebImage` to download the photos as required in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
// these are instance properties defined at the top of your class
var students: [PFObject]?
var studentPhotos=[String:UIImage]()

// This is in your fetch function
let studentsQuery = PFUser.Query()
    studentsQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: studentsArray! as! [AnyObject])

let query2 = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([studentsQuery])

query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    guard (error == nil) else {
        print(error)
        spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)
        return
    }

    if let results = results {
        self.students = results
            for object in results {
                if let studentProfilePictureFile = object.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {
                    studentProfilePictureFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (image: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
                    guard (error != nil) else {
                        print("Can't get profile picture: \(error)")
                        return
                    }

                if let studentProfilePicture = UIImage(data: image!) {
                    self.studentPhotos[object["username"]!]=studentProfilePicture
                }
            }
     }
     spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)
     self.tableview.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.students != nil {
        return self.students!.count
    }
    return 0 
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StudentsInClassInformationTableViewCell

    cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    let student = self.students[indexPath.row]

    if let studentPhoto = self.studentPhotos[student["username"]!] {
        cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.image = studentProfilePictureResults[indexPath.row] 
    } else {
        cell.studentProfilePictureImageView.image = nil
    }

    cell.studentUsernameLabel.text = student["username"]!

    if let fullName = student["full_name"] {
        cell.studentNameLabel.text = fullName
    } else {
        cell.studentNameLabel.text = ""
    return cell
}
```

A few other pointers;

- The use of _ to separate words in field names isn't really used in the iOS world; camelCase is preferred, so `fullName` rather than `full_name`
- It looks like your Parse query could be more efficient if you had a `class` field or reference object so that you didn't need to supply an array of other class members.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, Paul! I had to do a little bit of debugging and will edit your answer in a few days based on a few problems I had, but overall a clean and simple way to do it! Thanks again!